# Spurious failure of std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak in case the value equals to expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I am confused about spurious failures of std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak.

1. Could compare_exchange_weak fail in case the value of the atomic variable was the expected one?
2. If the answer is yes: Is there a way to know whether the value was the expected one or not? Because my code assumes that if the CAS failed then the value was not the expected one.
3. In particular, does compare_exchange_weak set 'expected' argument to the current value even in case of a spurious failure? In such a case, this value might either be the expected one (in case the CAS failed because of some timing issues…) or not?

*Edit*: To clarify the 3rd point: I didn't refer to changing the variable value itself by CAS, but changing the 'expected' argument reference. The question is whether compare_exchange_weak changes this reference to the current value of the variable - both generally and particularly in case of a spurious failure. I ask it because my code assumes that after the CAS, the 'expected' argument holds the current value. (According to the answers I got to the 2nd question, I assume that the answer is that 'expected' argument is never updated in the weak version. Correct?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Yes. It is the definition of spurious failure: it acts as if real value is not equal to expected even if they are.

2) Use `compare_exchange_strong` if you must know that or ensure that no spurious failure occurs.

3) No. it does not. It would violate contract: write only if `real == expected`, but it would load value to `expected`, even if it is the same one:

> N3797
>   **[atomics.types.operations.req]**/25
>
> Remark: A weak compare-and-exchange operation may fail spuriously. That is, even when the contents of memory referred to by expected and object are equal, it may return false and store back to expected the same memory contents that were originally there.

Comment: @galym added Standard quote

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't completely address my question, since it relates only to the case where expected and object are equal, and since it states "may" which doesn't sound like a guarantee. Is there no guarantee as to whether the expected reference is set to the current value of the atomic variable by compare_weak_exchange or not?

Comment: @galym There are three possible outcomes. *"good"*: `expected` == `object`. Stores `desired` value into `object`, `expected` is not changed, but it does not matter as it equals object anyway. *"bad"*: `expected` != `object`. Loads real `object` value into `expected`. *"spurious failure"*: `expected` == `object`. It still may work, as if it was 'bad' case: loads real `object` value into `expected` (in reality it does not change it as expected is equal to object)

Comment: I thought that _"spurious failure"_ includes also the case of `expected`!=`object`, and that the spurious failure in this case would be reflected in the not-updated value of `object`. If _"spurious failure"_ can occur only when `expected`==`object`, then there is no such concern. So when the weak CAS returns, the 'expected' argument **is** ensured to hold the current value in any case, which is what I wanted to figure. Right?

Comment: @galym Yes, expected is always hold current value of object.   Spurious failure when expected != object would defeat purpose of CAS operation and kill all it usefulness in synchronisation.

Comment: Wait a second... If that is the case then I don't understand the answer to question no. 2 - there **is** a way to know whether the value was the expected one - by simply checking `expected` value. This way it is also very easy to distinguish between a spurious failure and a real failure: In case `compare_exchange_weak` returned false - if `expected` value changed it was a real failure, else it was a spurious failure. Am I wrong?
But if I check it myself in my code, it is probably less efficient then just use `compare_exchange_strong` and let it ensure the CAS succeeds. Right?

Comment: In which case would a spurious failure happen?

Answer (score 5):

The weak exchange functions can fail to update, in order to have a higher-performance implementation under the hood.  They tend to be used in loop checks where it doesn't so much matter because it will get it on the next loop iteration.

So, specific answers...

1. Yes, the failure is that it can fail to update if value == expected_value.
2. If you truly need to know in a reliable way, don't use the weak version of these functions.  Go for the strong ones instead.
3. No, it will never overwrite the value if it is not the expected value.

Comment: Could you please refer to my clarification of the 3rd question? thanks!